# Sequelize Create a new instance and add association

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

I've looked at the documentation and read through some issues related to this on the sequelize github repo but so far haven't found any solutions to this, IMHO, simple operation. 
I have two models: Users and Cards. They are associated with a one-to-one relationship.

```
Orders.create({
  date: req.body.date,
  ...
  card: req.body.card //FK to a card ID
})
```

req.body.card is the id of the card. When I get the created object back though card is null.

I also tried creating the order first and then adding an association after but haven't had any luck with that either. I found some stuff about a `set` function that would set the association but I only saw examples of it with `hasMany` relationships.

I'm not trying to do anything fancy - just want to set the card id in the card field on an Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your model definition:

```
Orders.hasOne(models.Cards, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'card', });
```

1. In your definition, the foreign key will be placed on the `cards` table.
2. Naming the `foreignKey` as `id` will collide with the models own `id` field.

Try the following:

```
const Card = sequelize.define('card', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});

const Order = sequelize.define('order', {
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});

Order.hasOne(Card, { foreignKey: 'order_id' }); // if foreignKey is not included, will default to orderId

const order = await Order.create({
  name: 'first order'
})

const card = await Card.create({
  name: 'first card',
  order_id: order.id
})
```

Comment: so if the associated is set as `card` it should create cardId? It doesn't appear to be doing that.

Comment: Orders.hasOne(models.Cards, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      as: 'card',
    });

Comment: @MattSich I don't think that will work because that says you want a foreign key called `id` on the `Order` model, but the `Order` model already has an `id`. Could you post your model definitions in your question? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MattSich Just updated my answer. I also pushed an experiment up to Github https://github.com/mcranston18/sequelize-experiments/blob/master/card-orders.js

Comment: I am facing same issues here discussed. So what I understand is: 1) Associations only add fields to the "table" structure, 2) I have to "manually" populate the model field before create, save or update, 3) I cant populate with an object. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated